# UIWebView - Enable Right Click on Webpages

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my app and all is working well, but certain annoying webpages have disabled the ability for the user to right click to select text and display the copy-paste menu controller. I need to re-enable these actions for the user on these webpages. I suspect the answer has something to do with injecting Javascript into the page on `webViewDidFinishLoading:`, but I'm not sure how to craft this Javascript. Does anyone have any ideas?

From what I've inspected on the webpage, I see that it is disabling selection in the CSS. They are loading it via an external stylesheet file, if that information helps.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/styleSheet.css?hash=174">
```

which contains

```
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

I've tried injecting the following, but it's not working.

```
NSString* css = @"\"body { -webkit-user-select: default; }\"";
NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
                "styleNode.type = \"text/css\";\n"
                "var styleText = document.createTextNode(%@);\n"
                "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
                "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n",css];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

However, if I use desktop Safari Web Inspector on my UIWebView, and change the page's external CSS sheet to -`webkit-user-select:` to `default`, it works. I just need a way of being able to do this in my code. But if I add this line to the html page, below where the stylesheet is loaded, it does not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/styleSheet.css?hash=174">
<style type="text/css">body { background: #AAA; -webkit-user-select: default; }</style>
```

This what I'm seeing in Safari Web Inspector. For some reason, my style addition, made after the stylesheet, is still being overrun.

[image: Safari Inspector]

How can I change the `-webkit-user-select:` to default? I prefer an answer that uses Javascript as opposed to adding it to an htmlString and reloading the page.

**SOLVED:**

So changing the parameter to `auto` works, like in the following.

```
NSString* css = @"\"body { -webkit-user-select: auto; }\"";
NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
                "styleNode.type = \"text/css\";\n"
                "var styleText = document.createTextNode(%@);\n"
                "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
                "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n",css];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: try @"var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.style["-webkit-user-select"] = 'default';"

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried executing that via `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.style[\"-webkit-user-select\"] = 'default';"]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I found that should be something like this @"document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='default';" But i think you have to do it every time on reload.

Comment: I tried running `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='default';"];`, but it didn't work. I have a feeling that the external stylesheet is being loaded after my calls, because in Safari Inspector, it's seeing the JS for `-webkit-user-select=default`, but it has a strikethrough through it even though the code is being placed after external stylesheet line. Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: First `"-webkit-user-select: auto | none | text;"` then you can try !important atribute to css like `"document.body.style.cssText += '-webkit-user-select: auto !important;'"` OR `document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='auto !important'` This will override all the css rules that will load after if they dont have important themselves.

Comment: Ah ok, so "auto" works. Not sure why "default" doesn't work, but I was able to change the code. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This will target only the body Element you can target all the elements with `*` like `* { -webkit-user-select: auto !important; }` Because child elements can have their userselect to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `"-webkit-user-select: auto | none | text;"` webkitUserSelect Takes only this values.
Then

```
Nsstring *OverrideCssRules = @"document.body.style.cssText += '-webkit-user-select: auto !important;'"; OR @"document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='auto !important'";
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:OverrideCssRules];
```